# Javascript string argument is undefined, cannot access .length property

Tags: javascript, string, methods, parameters

So I'm working on freecodecamp challenge where i need to decode ceasar ciphers. I've  made a secondary function that is called from the main function to decode each word in the string. I'm having issues in that secondary code because it keeps on giving me the error that the string argument set as the parameter is undefined and that i cannot access length. Can someone please elucidate what's going on?

Disclaimer: I'm new to coding and spent the last 30 minutes searching for an answer to this problem and I can't find one. I feel like this fix should be easy and simple and apologize in advance if anyone finds this question redundant.

Here is the code:

```
function rot13(str) { // LBH QVQ VG!
  var stringArray = [];
  stringArray = str.split(" ");
  var value = stringArray.length;
  var decodedWords = [];
  var iCount = 0;

  while(iCount < value){
    decodedWords.push(decodeWord(stringArray[i]));
    iCount++;
  }

  return decodeWord("Confused!");

}

function decodeWord(word) {

    var decodedWord = "";

    for (i = 0; i < word.length; i++){

      var cipherVal = word.charCodeAt(i);
      var decodedVal = cipherVal;

      if( cipherVal >= 97 && cipherVal <= 109 || cipherVal >= 65 && cipherVal <= 77){
        decodedVal = cipherVal + 13;
      }

      else if(cipherVal >= 110 && cipherVal <= 122 || cipherVal >= 78 && 
 cipherVal <= 90){
        decodedVal = cipherVal - 13;
      }

      decodedWord += String.fromCharCode(decodedVal);
    }
    return decodedWord;
  }
```

Thanks for any advice! Much Appreciated.

Comment: `stringArray[i]` Where does the `i` come from?

Comment: `console.log(word)`, and you'll see it's undefined.  Need to change `i` to `iCount` (or vice versa), and how bout providing some items in the `stringArray`?

Answer (score 0):

In your first function, `i` inside the loop should be `iCount`:

```
var iCount = 0;
while(iCount < value) {
    decodedWords.push(decodeWord(stringArray[iCount]));
    iCount++;
}
```

The `decodeWord` function was complaining that `word` was undefined, because you were passing it a member of stringArray by an index that was undefined (`i`). If you grab an item by a defined index (`iCount`), `decodeWord` will receive a defined `word` and be able to grab its length.

Of course you'll probably also want `rot13` to return the encoded version of the input string rather than the encoded version of "Confused!":

```
return decodedWords.join(" ");
```

Comment: Oh my god. I am embarrassed haha. I started messing around with the code after I encountered some errors and was troubleshooting and forgot to change the count variable in the while loop so that when I fixed the other bugs I totally overlooked this one. Sorry about that and thanks for helping me out. Sounds like I've been coding for too long and need to take a break...haha

Comment: No need to be, those things slip by all the time!

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you made a mistake in this
**`decodedWords.push(decodeWord(stringArray[i]));`**

change it to

**`decodedWords.push(decodeWord(stringArray[iCount]));`**

Hope it works. Let me know for any issues